# Conditional like: if application started from IDE then (do this) else (do nothing)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, compiler-construction, ide

There is a way to execute a part of code ONLY if the application is launched from the IDE?.

I want to make a conditional where if application is launched from the VS IDE then do one thing but if application is launched manually from the compilation (from windows explorer, clicking in the compiled app, etc...) then do other thing.

This is possible?

Something like this, but changing **#Debug** to (Unknown thing...) :

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
#If DEBUG Then
        Me.Location = New Point(Form1.Right, Form1.Top)
#Else
        Dim BorderWidth = (Me.Width - Me.ClientSize.Width)
        Me.Location = New Point((Form1.Location.X + (Form1.Width + BorderWidth)), Form1.Location.Y)
#End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really want to do is detect if there is a debugger attached to your application's process.

To do that, test the value of the [`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx). If it returns `true`, then a debugger is attached.

Of course, you can have a debugger other than Visual Studio attached to the process and that will still cause `IsAttached` to return `true`. And you can start an application from Visual Studio *without* the debugger attached (usually by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>), and that will cause `IsAttached` to return `false`. But chances are good that whatever code you conditionally execute should run in all cases that a debugger is attached, and should *not* run whenever a debugger is *not* attached, regardless of which debugger it is.

Note that this is different from `#If DEBUG`, since that tests whether you're running a Debug build of the application. Debug builds have nothing to do with whether a debugger is attached. You can have a Debug build without the debugger attached, or attach a debugger to the Release build.

***But***, I really don't recommend using this for what you propose in the question. How will you debug problems with window placement if you're doing it differently each time a debugger is attached?

Comment: Thankyou so much, I have a stupid question, I'm a bit lost with the term "Debugger attachment", if I select in my OS a default debugger for my applications instead of the VS debugger, then the default debugger is "attached"? or is only "defined"? I knoe that can't be attached inside the compiled code but, I don't know what mean attaching a debugger sorry.

Comment: @Elektro I'm not sure what you mean by selecting a default debugger in the OS. When an app crashes with an unhandled exception, the operating system will prompt you to attach a post-mortem debugger to the process if one is available. That will be the case if Visual Studio is installed. But the debugger isn't attached until you request that it be. Otherwise, when you press `F5` or otherwise run your app from VS, the debugger is automatically attached, no matter if it's a Debug or Release build. You have to press `Ctrl`+`F5` to launch without the debugger attached, or start it outside of VS.

Comment: All code is compiled. It has to be in order to execute it. So that has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a command line switch to enable the extra feature, and pass that in from Visual Studio via the Debugging settings?

Or use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`.